Nginx proxy_pass connection fail 111 with containerised flask-app
I have a container Ive built locally called my-flask-app which is running flask behind gunicorn. So the dockerfile ends with:
CMD gunicorn --worker-class gevent \
  --access-logfile - \
  --workers $WORKERS \
  --threads $THREADS \
  --reload \
  --bind :$PORT_APP \
  wsgi:app

PORT_APP is 3000. So localhost:3000 is my lovely app.
Ive spun up an ec2, installed docker + nginx. Ive run locally docker push my-flask-app to aws ecr.
And on my ec2 ive done docker pull my-flask-app. And I can run it: docker run -p 8080:3000 my-flask-app.
I can go to the browser: my-ec2-address.com:8080 and I get my lovely app.
I go into nginx and I create my conf:
server {
        listen 80 default_server;

        server_name my-address.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
}

Then I go to my-ec2-address.com and I get the dreaded 502, and the nginx error logs shout: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: my-home-ip, server: my-address.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "my-address.com"
What am I getting wrong or being stupid about?

proxy_pass should point to the exposed port on the host system: 8080.
